# Order/Sort a nested generic list

Tags: c#, list, generics, sorting, sql-order-by

I have two entities that are something like that:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<Director> Directors { get; set; };

    public int Year { get; set; }
}

public class Director
{
    public int DirectorID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I want to order a list of Movies by the name of the Director:

```
Movies.OrderBy (??? => ???)
```

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like Movies can have many Directors.  Which one do you want to use to sort by?

Comment: That's logically not possible because a movie can have more than one director.  Do you order by the name of the FIRST director?  What if a movie has no directors?

Comment: why using get set on public variable?

Comment: @Marius those are auto-implemented properties in C#

Comment: These are not my real entities, I just wrote something more "clean" for the question. 
@Eric A movie can't have no directors. Ordering like L.B show on the reply below satisfies my condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var orderedMovies =
    movies.OrderBy(movie => 
                    String.Join(",", movie.Directors
                                             .OrderBy(dir => dir.Name)
                                             .Select(dir => dir.Name)
                    )
    );
```